# cv2.findContours() and cv2.drawContours() do not show intended results

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to find the contours of each shape in the following image:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pePdY.png)

I tried the following code:

```
!pip install opencv-python
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from google.colab import drive
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
drive.mount('/content/drive')

path='/content/drive/My Drive/NewApproach.png'
img= cv.imread(path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

gray=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur=cv.GaussianBlur(gray,(13,13),0)
blur8 = blur.astype(np.uint8)
canny=cv.Canny(blur8,110,120,3)
dilated=cv.dilate(canny,(-1,-1),iterations=2)
(cnt, heirarchy)=cv.findContours(dilated.copy(),cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
rgb=cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv.drawContours(rgb,cnt,-1,(0,255,0),2)

def find_contour_areas(cnt):
  areas=[]
  for contour in cnt:
    cont_area=cv.contourArea(contour)
    areas.append(cont_area)
  return areas

sorted_contours_by_area=sorted(cnt, key=cv.contourArea, reverse=True)

for sc in sorted_contours_by_area:
  duplicate_img=cv.imread(path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
  #duplicate_img_color = cv.cvtColor(duplicate_img, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
  #cv.drawContours(duplicate_img_color,[sc],-1,(0,255,0),3)
  cv.drawContours(duplicate_img,[sc],-1,(0,255,0),3)
  cv.waitKey(0)
  cv2_imshow(duplicate_img)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

But the result is taking the shapes shown in the following image:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUAr6.png)
which are not exactly the shapes one would see at first sight.

Could someone help me fixing this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the original image?

Comment: Why are you blurring the image so much? You do not need to blur. That likely is your issue. Your shapes are spread out or merge if you blur.

Comment: `cv.findContours(dilated.copy(), ...` --  are you still using OpenCV 2.4? I'm curious how this keeps propagating..

Comment: @eldesgraciado Sorry but I can just provide the ones I attached

Comment: @fmw42 no blur still gives same poblem...

Comment: Try thresholding on color using cv2.inRange(). Then use morphology if needed to clean that up. Then get contours as suggested by @Dan Mask above.

Comment: @fmw42 Oh, I wasn't suggesting anything. Just wondering (since `findContours` only returns 2 values in either 2.x or 4.x, and from 3.2 it doesn't mangle the input image, thus not requiring that deep copy) whether the OP was using an ancient release or just copying things mindlessly.